# Why can't I retrieve a URL from an XPath query?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have the following script, to find an image on a page and download it:

```
from lxml import html
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.example.com/pages/page0987/'
usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = usock.read()
usock.close()

tree = html.fromstring(data)

src = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/img/@src')
urllib.urlretrieve(src, "local-filename.jpg")
```

I get a webpage, access an `<img>` element on this page (I tr to find it using an XPath query), then I get a `src` attribute of this element and then try to download the image using this url from the source.

But something is wrong; Python says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sergey\Desktop\dlImg.py", line 15, in <module>
    urllib.urlretrieve(src, "local-filename.jpg")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 94, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 228, in retrieve
    url = unwrap(toBytes(url))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 1060, in unwrap
    url = url.strip()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `tree.xpath()` query returns a **list**, not a single match. At the very least index for the first item:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(src[0], "local-filename.jpg")
```

or use a loop over the results. Take into account that the list can be empty as well (no matches found).